# How to pass async data to google-charts-angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create a chart based on data I get from an API call. For this I'm using the google-charts-angular package. This is what my html looks like :

```
<google-chart [title]="title" [type]="type" [data]="data"  [options]="options"></google-chart>
```

I only need to pass the data to the chart. I do that in my component.ts file. First I tested it with random data I made up:

```
title = 'Issues';
  type = 'Gantt';
  data = [
    ['1', 'Read', 'whatever', //More data ....],
    ['2', 'Write', 'whatever' // More data ...,
  ];
  columnNames = [
    ['string', 'Task ID'],
    ['string', 'Task Name'],
    ['string', 'Resource'],
    // More colums ...
  ];
```

This works like it should. Now I want to use the data from the API. GetIssues Returns an Observable using the http.get() function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiService.getIssues().subscribe(response => {})
}
```

Problem is I don't know how to get the async data from the subscribe to the chart. I tried to push new array to the data array but that didn't work:

```
    issues = [];
    data = [
        ['1', 'Read', 'whatever', new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 3),  1, 100, null],
        ['2', 'Write', 'whatever', new Date(2015, 0, 4), new Date(2015, 0, 7),  1, 100, null],
      ];
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.apiService.getIssues().subscribe(response => {
              this.issues = response;
              if (this.issues) {
                let id = 3;
                for (let issue of this.issues) {
                  this.data.push([id, issue.title, 'whatever', new Date(2015, 0, 4), new Date(2015, 0, 7),  1, 100, null]);
                  id += 1;
                }
              }
            });
          }
```

The chart will show the two made up arrays in data, but not the new ones I want to add with push. I think the problem is that the chart is getting rendered before the subscribe finished. If that is really the problem I don't know how the render the chart after the asyc part finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.issues = this.apiService.getIssues();
    this.issues.subscribe(response => {
      this.data.push( ['1', response[0].title, 'whatever', new Date(2015, 0, 4), new Date(2015, 0, 7),  1, 100, null]);
    })
  }
```

And in template:

```
<div *ngIf="issues | async">
    <google-chart [title]="title" [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></google-chart>
</div>
```

What I did is

1. Http.get returns a Observable. I save it in variable called *issues*
2. Using *ngIf in my template I check if *issues* exists
3. In *ngIf I pipe to async to make sure it waits until Observable has returned something
4. I use subscribe on the *issues* and push just the values I need into data

What I don't know if this is a good way to do this and if it brings problems with it.